# jupyter notebook won't show images

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, opencv

```
#%%

from Utils.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
config = ConfigProvider.config()
```

and

```
#%%

inspected = cv2.imread(config.data.inspected_image_path, 0)
reference = cv2.imread(config.data.reference_image_path, 0)
diff = np.abs(inspected - reference)

plt.figure()
plt.title('inspected')
plt.imshow(inspected)

plt.show()
```

note `config.data.inspected_image_path` and `config.data.reference_image_path` are valid paths.

---

No errors appear, but no images are shown as well.

Running the same code from a python file does show the image.

I have something missing from the notebook.

This happens both when running using `jupyter notebook` and directly from PyCharm (pro)

How do I get to see images? all other answers I found just tell me to `plt.show()` but this obviously does not work.

I don't mind a `cv2` solution as well.

Comment: try using `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: @warped how to do that?

Comment: write `%matplotlib inline` into a cell in your jupyter notebook, then execute the cell, then execute the code you want to display.

Comment: @warped YES finally. that was a total waste of time. If you write an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a [matplotlib backend](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends).

You can do this with

```
%matplotlib inline
```

If you want to be able to interact with the plot, use

```
%matplotlib notebook
```